# is a doctor who do consults with children legally required to not do consults with adults?

Tags: medical

This is a real problem for me, my previous doctor who did consults with me until i was 17 passed then stopped my consults with him.

the frustrating part is that i was not well informed about what next to do, which other doctor can help me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what country you're talking about, so I'll answer from the United States perspective.

Yes, it is perfectly legal for a pediatrician to see adult patients. This happens often, especially when the person has a developmental disability, but it isn't unheard of in situations with perfectly healthy individuals.

---

If you want to switch to a PCP (primary care physician) who works with adults, it's best to get a recommendation from the pediatrician. Often you can just change to a doctor in the same hospital system, but typically your choice of doctors is more driven by your insurance coverage and the doctor's ability to take new patients. Your medical records can be transferred to your new PCP and I would suggest an orientation/meeting with your new PCP if you have any specific concerns that they would need to consult your previous doctor about. This is really part of the process of becoming an adult and being independant.

Comment: Of course, just because it's legal for the pediatrician to see adult patients, doesn't mean he has to do it.  He can choose not to. He may not feel as well qualified to treat adults, and there may be general professional standards discouraging it except in special situations.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, however the question is about the *legality* of doing it. The doctor (and more likely the institution they work for) is well within their rights to refer adult patients to PCP's that aren't pediatricians.

Comment: There is the contract type of illegality: his boss may have a policy that pediatricians cannot treat adults.

Comment: There is also the issue that medical care for children and medical care for adults is often very different, and paediatricians are specialised for the former - they may not feel comfortable treating an adult, especially the older the patients get.